# auto-generating MailChimp emails when posting on a Wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress, post, plugins, automation, mailchimp

I have a wordpress (WP) blog and wish to integrate it with my MailChimp (MC) Account. I need it to do the following:

whenever I publish a post on my WP blog, I want an email to be sent to the relevant MC list. the email should be auto-generated, and contain the design of the blog post, and the beginning of the content (with a "read more" link to the post itself on my blog).

Subscribing and list syncing is of course relevant too, but as I understand - these are trivial tasks and many plugins offer this functionality.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably going to be easiest to handle this at the MailChimp end - MailChimp have an RSS to email service that does most, if not all, of what you need and they've written [this tutorial](http://blog.mailchimp.com/rss-to-email-tutorial/).